# jQuery Geolocation : Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I have been browsing for hours now to find a solution.
I have a low knowledge of JavaScript, I am actually learning it.

I am encoutering a problem with getting the GPS position of my user. I want :
- **Get the position of the user (jQuery).**
- Transmit it to the server side via Ajax > PHP.

Here is my JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initCoords();
});

function initCoords() {
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateLocation, errorHandler, {enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 60000, timeout: 27000});
    } else
    {
        alert('Wrong browser.');
    }
}

function updateLocation(position)
{
    var longitude=position.coords.longitude;
    var latitude=position.coords.latitude;
    console.log(longitude);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../ajax/account/handlegeolocation",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"longitude": longitude, "latitude": latitude},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.message);
        },
        error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }).then(function () {
        setTimeout(updateLocation, 30);
    });
}

function errorHandler(error)
{
    console.log('Geolocation error : code ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
}
```

What I am surprised is what I see when loading the page.
The position is returned, but JS says the object that returns the position is undefined.

[image: Capture Results Jquery]

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not passing position object from

```
setTimeout(updateLocation, 30);
```

calling to function `initCoords` from timeout will solve your problem.

Or here is your code with some edit and without any error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initCoords();
});

function initCoords() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        getGeoLocation();
    } else {
        alert('Wrong browser.');
    }
}
function getGeoLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateLocation, errorHandler, { enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 60000, timeout: 27000 });
}
function updateLocation(position) {
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../ajax/account/handlegeolocation",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "longitude": longitude, "latitude": latitude },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.message);
        },
        error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }).then(function () {
        setTimeout(getGeoLocation, 30);
    });
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log('Geolocation error : code ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It is working, but not transmitting the data at the loading of the page. Meaning that the POST data are transmitted only once the first timeout is reached. Then, everything works correctly. Have you an idea ?

Comment: Nothing wrong in JavaScript.. Still if you are facing issue then it must be at server side. Also 30 milliseconds time is too less for update.